# Merging Repo A and Repo B into Repo C and publishing Repo C

Tags: github, hugo

I am attempting to automate a [HUGO Static Site Generation system](https://gohugo.io/).

- Repo A is content that would normally be in the `/Content` directory.
  Repo A will be changed often and consists of just .md files.
- Repo B is a Hugo Site complete with a Theme directory.
  Repo B never changes often.
- Repo C is to be a combination of Repo A and B and compiled when there is a new push to Repo A (the content).

I suspect GitHub Action can do this on some sort of push event of repo A.

Where do I begin researching how this would be performed?
Is there a better solution for maintaining the HUGO site and Hugo content in separate Repos?

FYI:  This is a HUGO Project, which is a static site generator.

Comment: An Elaboration on what I would like to do. I want to keep the content separate in another github repository.   So every push with updated content, would start some sort of pipeline rebuild.  Is there a way I can use GITHUB repos in the /config/modules.toml file?

Answer (score 1):

As described in "[Using git submodule for Hugo themes](https://www.andrewhoog.com/post/git-submodule-for-hugo-themes/)", you should not need 3 repositories, but 2.

One for content, which includes in the `themes/` folder your theme submodule repository.

You can then add a GitHub Action like [`jakejarvis/hugo-build-action`](https://github.com/jakejarvis/hugo-build-action) to build the site on each `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hugo Modules](https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/) to achieve what you have in mind. My setup is similar to yours--separate repo for content, the site itself, and I'm pulling themes as a Hugo module too.

### Here's how to do it

In your `module.toml` file (if you are using the `/config/` directory setup.

```
[[imports]]
  path = "gitlab.com/youronlyone/content"
  # BGN: /yuki/ content
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/en-ph"
      target = "content"
      lang = "en-ph"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/ja"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ja"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/ko"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ko"
  # END: /yuki/ content

  # BGN: /snoworld/ content
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "snoworld/en-ph"
      target = "content"
      lang = "en-ph"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "snoworld/ja"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ja"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "snoworld/ko"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ko"
  # END: /snoworld/ content

  # BGN: /techmagus/ content
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "techmagus/en-ph"
      target = "content"
      lang = "en-ph"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "techmagus/ja"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ja"
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "techmagus/ko"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ko"
  # END: /techmagus/ content

  # still needed
  [[mounts]]
    source = "content/en-ph"
    target = "content"
    lang = "en-ph"                                      # when in multihost / multilang mode
  [[mounts]]
    source = "content/ja"
    target = "content"
    lang = "ja"                                         # when in multihost / multilang mode
  [[mounts]]
    source = "content/ko"
    target = "content"
    lang = "ko"                                         # when in multihost / multilang mode
```

If you are using a single `config` file, just add `module.` prefix like so:

```
[module]
[[module.imports]]
  path = "gitlab.com/youronlyone/content"
  # BGN: /yuki/ content
    [[module.imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/en-ph"
      target = "content"
      lang = "en-ph"
    [[module.imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/ja"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ja"
    [[module.imports.mounts]]
      source = "yuki/ko"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ko"
  # END: /yuki/ content

  # still needed
  [[module.mounts]]
    source = "content/en-ph"
    target = "content"
    lang = "en-ph"                                      # when in multihost / multilang mode
```

As you can see in the above code, it is possible to support a multilingual site.

It is also possible to only pull a specific content, like so: (below is code for `/config/module.toml` setup)

```
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "love/en-ph"
      target = "content"
      lang = "en-ph"
      includeFiles = ["**/20160703-the-choice-2016.md"]
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "love/ja"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ja"
      includeFiles = ["**/20160703-the-choice-2016.md"]
    [[imports.mounts]]
      source = "love/ko"
      target = "content"
      lang = "ko"
      includeFiles = ["**/20160703-the-choice-2016.md"]
```

Or to pull from multiple repos.

Hugo modules is not only for content, it works for i18n, archetypes, data, static, etc. See [Module Config: mounts](https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/configuration/#module-config-mounts).

As long you've setup Hugo Modules correctly, the GH actions for Hugo will work since it is Hugo that pulls those separate repos during build time (not the GH action script).

Comment: Could I use github.com repo as a content virtual directory.  So every push to the content repo would start a new build.  Is this even a good idea.  Any complication to using something like netlify?